# Redis Python execute_command Redisearch

Tags: python, redis, redisearch

I am using python 3.6 in order to add some documents on a redis server ! So I use the command : `execute_command` with the module Redis.

In my exemple I want to add metadata to a redisearch document with :

```
c = 'FT.ADD idx doc 1 REPLACE FIELDS parameter'  + ' ' + a 

r.execute_command(c)
```

a is a str data. 
So i want to add parameter : a in the document doc. where 'a' is TEXT.

But when there is a space in `'str a'`, execute _command consider that it is a next argument even if I put quotes `("` or `')` on each side ...

For exemple : If `a = '"Test Test"'`, I will just find `"\"Test"` on the redis server ...

How can I deal with this ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `r.execute_command(['FT.ADD','idx','doc',1,'REPLACE','FIELDS', 'parameter',a]`?

Comment: When I use it I have this error :
DataError: Invalid input of type: 'list'. Convert to a byte, string or number first.

Comment: Did you try the https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-py

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
r.execute_command('FT.ADD', 'idx', 'doc', 1, 'REPLACE', 'FIELDS', 'parameter', 'a');
```